# for my computer science class I am working on operators

Tags: java, addition

[image]

how do i add totalprice of a Sandwhich that cost $3, chips cost $2, and soda cost $1

Comment: More detail please. We don't even know what language you're using.

Comment: you should look into some basic java tutorials

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include code as text within the question itself. Also, this site requires you to show some efforts first - what have you tried so far, where _exactly_ are you stuck? This is neither a coding service nor a basic tutorial.

Comment: ^^^ Post code in the text, indented by four spaces (If you do, will get syntax highlighting) instead of posting an image.

Comment: Illegible. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Okay as a fellow Computer Science student I will help you out.

to get your result the codes this

```
System.out.println(inputsandwhich + inputsoda + inputchips);
```

if you wanted to be really fancy you could do this

```
int sum;
sum = (inputsandwhich + inputsoda + inputchips); 
System.out.println(sum);
```